# Force BindingSource to update data/model

Tags: c#, user-interface, devexpress

I can't seem to figure this out and couldn't find any answers.

I have a Combobox binded to a property in my model.
I'll just copy and paste key lines in my code:

```
       this.m_typeCombobox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("EditValue", this.m_bindingSource, "Type", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

My Model:

```
public class TypeConfig : INotifyPropertyChanged
{     
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
           private EnumType<eLType> m_type;
    public EnumType<eLType> Type
    {
        get { return m_type; }
        set
        {
            if (m_type!= value)
            {
                m_type= value;
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Type"));
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to have the model updated on combobox EditValueChanged event but it looks like the model is updated later. EditValueChanged is the latest called event when changing.

I have tried this:

```
void m_TypeCombobox_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           m_bindingSource.EndEdit(); //this doesn't work 
          //need to have the new value here
    }
```

Here's what MSDN says:

When the EndEdit method is called, all pending changes are applied to the underlying data source.
This method has no effect unless the objects contained by the data source implement the IEditableObject interface. If the objects do not implement the IEditableObject interface, changes to the data are copied to the underlying data source immediately after each change.

So, from my undesrstanding the model should be immediately updated when changing the combobox value.

I'm using a DevExpress combobox that's pretty much the same as a normal WinForms combobox.

How can i workaround this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

try to make binding to "Value" property, rather than "EditValue"
I hope it helps you

Comment: seems like this type DevExpress.XtraEditors.ComboBoxEdit does not provide a Value property. I have to work with Editvalue.

Answer (score 0):

For BindingSource.EndEdit to do anything, You need to implement System.ComponentModel.IEditableObject for the items contained within the BindingSource.

When you invoke "EndEdit" on the binding source, it subsequently invokes the corresponding IEditableObject.EndEdit() method on the items in it's list that implement IEditableObject.

Having said that, I am having some issues with EndEdit not being called for all items that BeginEdit has been called on when, eg, the user closes the form.